# Error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: host bind array too small

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to understand when this oracle error occurs 'Error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: host bind array too small'

I have a plsql block and it has a normal annonymus block which has DBMS_output.put_line and also has DBMS_output.put in a for loop and in the code its calls another package in for loop itself and the out variables  like success( as S) and errormessage (as err_msg) of package are displayed using DBMS_output.put and the out put gets printed for few records but suddenly a above  error occurs and blocks gets completed don't how this happemed. Can any one explain why such error occurs.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: What version of Oracle and of SQL/Plus? See [this discussion](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1633289) for the same issue - in Oracle 9i (or later Oracle versions being accessed with an earlier SQL/Plus version) there appears to be a 255 character limit on `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs on the client-side, not on the server-side, so it's an error with specific versions of `sqlplus`. It happens when `sqlplus` utility tries to read the `dbms_output` buffer from the server-side to the client-side buffer, and the buffer contains a string that is more than 255 characters long. So error happens when:

1. you are using `sqlplus` with version less than 10.2 and the version of Database server is 10.2 or higher. For example:

   1. client is 10.1.0.5 and server is 12.2.9
   2. client is 10.1.0.5 and server is 10.2.0.5
   3. client is 10.1.0.5 and server is 11.2.0.1
2. the `serveroutput on`  option is set
3. you have put a line with more than 255 characters into the `dbms_output` buffer.

Please, note that if your server is 10.1.0.5 or less (9.2.0.8) you would get different error: ORA-20000: `ORU-10028: line length overflow, limit of 255 chars per line`.

### Demo

Put 256 characters and we get the error:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(a => rpad('1',256,'1'));
end;
/
ERROR:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: host bind array too small
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Or you can do it in a slightly different way:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
begin
  dbms_output.put(a => rpad('1',200,'1'));
  dbms_output.put(a => rpad('1',200,'1'));
  dbms_output.put_line('');
end;
/
ERROR:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: host bind array too small
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Put 255 characters and it' ok we get the output:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(a => rpad('1',255,'1'));
end;
/
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111
```

### How to solve

**Option 1:**

Oracle fixed the error in the 10.2 release, so if you upgrade your server-side and the client-side components to at least 10.2.0.5, the error will be fixed.

**Option 2:**

If you absolutely have to use 10.1 version or older versions of `sqlplus` (and version of Database is 10.2 or higher) and you cannot rewrite your pl/sql code that generates long characters string, then you can work around this bug using [dbms_output.get_lines](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i1000253) (or `dbms_output.get_line`) procedures:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
begin
  -- enable the server-side buffer. When SET SERVEROUTPUT ON sqlplus does it automatically.
  -- Now we do it manually.
  dbms_output.enable(1000000);
  
  dbms_output.put_line(a => rpad('1',300,'1'));
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Then use this block just to get the content of the buffer:

```
variable l_cursor REFCURSOR
set autoprint on
declare
  -- Then use this block to get the contents of the buffer.
  l number:=10000;
  l_array DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY;
begin
  dbms_output.get_lines(l_array,l);
  open :l_cursor for select * from table(l_array);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Answer (score -1):

usually this error will occur when you either try to set a variable with too big a value. for instance.

```
v_number number(2);
BEGIN
  v_number := 100;
END;
```

or when you try to save text into a number variable

```
v_number number(2);
BEGIN
  v_number := 'a';
END;
```

see here for more info: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora06502.php

Comment: The OP's error is `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: host bind array too small` not `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large` or `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error`.

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue. In SQL PLUS the dbms_output.put_line has a limitation upto 255 characters. If this limit is exceeded then 'Error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: host bind array too small' get pop up. But this will not affect the execution of the block.