# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: host bind array too small

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to read a string array from Oracle stored procedure and I am getting this error

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: host bind array too small.
```

The stored procedure is working but when I call it from c# the error happened so I think something in my C# code is not right. Here is my code calling the stored procedure

```
            string[] myArray2 = new string[NoOfDay];
            OracleString[] arrDays = null;

            OracleParameter P_result2 = new OracleParameter("UTILDAYS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20);
            P_result2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            P_result2.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
            P_result2.Size = myArray2.Count();
            P_result2.ArrayBindSize = new int[myArray2.Count()];
            cmd.Parameters.Add(P_result2);
            //cmd.Parameters["L"].Value = myArray;
             try
             {
                on.Open();
                //cmd.CommandText = sSQL;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); <---- Error happened here after executing this line!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                arrDays = (OracleString[]) cmd.Parameters["UTILDAYS"].Value;
                //OracleString[] arrDay = (OracleString[])cmd.Parameters["DAYS"].Value;
                con.Close();


              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                          
              }
```

Here is my stored procedure. I am using Toad.

```
TYPE myArray2 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETUTILDAYS (
 "DATE1"       IN     VARCHAR2,
   "DATE2"       IN     VARCHAR2,
   "TESTER"      IN     VARCHAR2, 
  "UTILDAYS"      OUT GETUTIL.myArray2
 )
IS
   currDate   VARCHAR2 (20);
   prevDate   VARCHAR2 (20);
   total      NUMBER;
   total0     NUMBER;
   cnt        NUMBER;
   firstR     NUMBER;

   CURSOR V_CUR
   IS
        SELECT idle_category,
               TO_CHAR (CAST (probed_time AS DATE), 'MM-DD-YYYY') AS pd
          FROM inprogress
         WHERE tester_id = TESTER
               AND probed_time >
                      TO_TIMESTAMP (CONCAT (DATE1, ' 00:00:00'),
                                    'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
               AND probed_time <
                      TO_TIMESTAMP (CONCAT (DATE2, ' 23:59:59'),
                                    'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
      ORDER BY probed_time ASC;
/******************************************************************************
   NAME:       GetUtilisation
   PURPOSE:

   REVISIONS:
   Ver        Date        Author           Description
   ---------  ----------  ---------------  ------------------------------------
   1.0        12/12/2022   jyow       1. Created this procedure.

   NOTES:

   Automatically available Auto Replace Keywords:
      Object Name:     GetUtilisation
      Sysdate:         12/12/2022
      Date and Time:   12/12/2022, 12:03:01 AM, and 12/12/2022 12:03:01 AM
      Username:        jyow (set in TOAD Options, Procedure Editor)
      Table Name:       (set in the "New PL/SQL Object" dialog)

******************************************************************************/
BEGIN
   total := 0;
   total0 := 0;
   cnt := 1;
   firstR:=1;
   --UTILBYDAY:= new GETUTIL.myArray();
   --UTILBYDAY.EXTEND(14);
   --UTILBYDAY (1) := 1;
   --UTILBYDAY (2) := 2;
   --THEDAYS (1) :='TESTING';

   --select idle_category from inprogress where tester_id=TESTER and probed_time>to_timestamp(CONCAT(DATE1, ' 00:00:00'), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and probed_time<to_timestamp(CONCAT(DATE2, ' 23:59:59'), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
   FOR V_REC IN V_CUR
   LOOP
      currDate := V_REC.pd;

      IF firstR = 1
      THEN
         firstR:=99;
         prevDate := V_REC.pd;
      END IF;

      IF prevDate = currDate
      THEN
         --prevDate:=currDate;
         total := total + 1;

         IF V_REC.idle_category = 0
         THEN
            total0 := total0 + 1;
         END IF;
      ELSE
         --UTILBYDAY (cnt) := total0 / total * 100;
         UTILDAYS (cnt) := prevDate;
         --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Values' || UTILBYDAY (cnt));
         --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Days' || UTILDAYS (cnt));
         cnt := cnt + 1;
         total := 0;
         total0 := 0;
         prevDate := currDate;
      END IF;
      
   --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Values from v_var that are not null' || V_REC.idle_category);
   END LOOP;
   --UTILBYDAY (cnt) := total0 / total * 100;
    UTILDAYS (cnt) := currDate;
      --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Values' || UTILBYDAY (cnt));
      --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Days' || UTILDAYS (cnt));
END GETUTILDAYS;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your procedure appears to work without any exceptions [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4P3EJHOy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse engineering your procedure, you appear to want to count the number of entries per day for a given tester and what percentage of those have `idle_category` of `0`. If so, then you can simplify the procedure to:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE getutil IS
  TYPE myArray1 IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  TYPE myArray2 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETUTILDAYS (
  DATE1      IN  VARCHAR2,
  DATE2      IN  VARCHAR2,
  TESTER     IN  INPROGRESS.TESTER_ID%TYPE, 
  UTILBYDAYS OUT GETUTIL.myArray1,
  UTILDAYS   OUT GETUTIL.myArray2
)
IS
   cnt PLS_INTEGER := 0;

   CURSOR V_CUR
   IS
     SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(probed_time), 'MM-DD-YYYY') AS pd,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN idle_category = 0 THEN 1 END) AS total0,
            COUNT(*) AS total
     FROM   inprogress
     WHERE  tester_id = TESTER
     AND    probed_time >= TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE1, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
     AND    probed_time <  TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE2, 'mm-dd-yyyy') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
     GROUP BY TRUNC(probed_time)
     ORDER BY TRUNC(probed_time) ASC;
BEGIN
   FOR V_REC IN V_CUR
   LOOP
     cnt := cnt + 1;
     UTILDAYS(cnt) := v_rec.pd;
     UTILBYDAYS(cnt) := v_rec.total0 / v_rec.total * 100;
   END LOOP;
END GETUTILDAYS;
/
```

and then removing the cursor, you can simplify it further to:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETUTILDAYS (
  DATE1      IN  VARCHAR2,
  DATE2      IN  VARCHAR2,
  TESTER     IN  INPROGRESS.TESTER_ID%TYPE, 
  UTILBYDAYS OUT GETUTIL.myArray1,
  UTILDAYS   OUT GETUTIL.myArray2
)
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(probed_time), 'MM-DD-YYYY'),
         COUNT(CASE WHEN idle_category = 0 THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) * 100
  BULK COLLECT INTO
         utildays,
         utilbydays
  FROM   inprogress
  WHERE  tester_id = TESTER
  AND    probed_time >= TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE1, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
  AND    probed_time <  TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE2, 'mm-dd-yyyy') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
  GROUP BY TRUNC(probed_time)
  ORDER BY TRUNC(probed_time) ASC;
END GETUTILDAYS;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE inprogress(probed_time, tester_id, idle_category) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-01-01 00:00:00' + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '1' HOUR,
       1,
       CASE
       WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP '2022-01-01 00:00:00' + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '1' HOUR)
            < EXTRACT(DAY FROM TIMESTAMP '2022-01-01 00:00:00' + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '1' HOUR)
       THEN 0
       ELSE 1
       END
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24 * 24;
```

*Note: there should be 24 days of data and the number of rows with `idle_category = 0` should increase by 1 each day.*

Then you can test it with:

```sql
DECLARE
  arr1 GETUTIL.MYARRAY1;
  arr2 GETUTIL.MYARRAY2;
  idx PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  getutildays('01-01-2022', '01-24-2022', 1, arr1, arr2);
  idx := arr1.FIRST;
  WHILE idx IS NOT NULL LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(arr2(idx) || ': ' || arr1(idx));
    idx := arr1.NEXT(idx);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 01-01-2022: 4.16666666666666666666666666666666666667
> 01-02-2022: 8.33333333333333333333333333333333333333
> 01-03-2022: 12.5
> 01-04-2022: 16.66666666666666666666666666666666666667
> 01-05-2022: 20.83333333333333333333333333333333333333
> 01-06-2022: 25
> 01-07-2022: 29.16666666666666666666666666666666666667
> 01-08-2022: 33.33333333333333333333333333333333333333
> 01-09-2022: 37.5
> 01-10-2022: 41.66666666666666666666666666666666666667
> 01-11-2022: 45.83333333333333333333333333333333333333
> 01-12-2022: 50
> 01-13-2022: 54.16666666666666666666666666666666666667
> 01-14-2022: 58.33333333333333333333333333333333333333
> 01-15-2022: 62.5
> 01-16-2022: 66.66666666666666666666666666666666666667
> 01-17-2022: 70.83333333333333333333333333333333333333
> 01-18-2022: 75
> 01-19-2022: 79.16666666666666666666666666666666666667
> 01-20-2022: 83.33333333333333333333333333333333333333
> 01-21-2022: 87.5
> 01-22-2022: 91.66666666666666666666666666666666666667
> 01-23-2022: 95.83333333333333333333333333333333333333
> 01-24-2022: 100
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1j_G6c41)

Answer (score 0):

As per the error it clearly shows that this is an issue on your Database side.  This error usually occurs when you either try to set a variable whose value is too big.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65503707/): So error happens when:

> you are using sqlplus with version less than 10.2 and the version of
> Database server is 10.2 or higher. For example:
>
> 1. client is 10.1.0.5 and server is 12.2.9
> 2. client is 10.1.0.5 and server is 10.2.0.5
> 3. client is 10.1.0.5 and server is 11.2.0.1 the serveroutput on option is set
>
> you have put a line with more than 255 characters into the dbms_output
> buffer.

Comment: I am not using sqlplus. I am using Toad and the stored procedure work well. I have disabled dbms_output but still getting the error from c#.

Comment: I have included my stored procedure for reference. Any help is appreciated.